# One word for shelter-giving

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word in English which can replace *someone/something who gives shelter* or *shelter-giving*?

I am not only interested in a person who gives shelter but something which gives a sense of shelter e.g. *shelter-giving earth.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like *sheltering* given in another answer. There is also [harbour, or harbouring](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/harbour) (harbor or harboring) and safe harbour (safe harbor).

Comment: Safe harbor or safe harbour can be used, too.

Comment: @KristinaLopez even better. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just *sheltering*? Use the noun as a verb; it's perfectly appropriate in English.

For example, take a look at this novel and movie title:

[image: The Sheltering Sky]

Answer (score 2):

A *hotelier* is someone who provides shelter and lodging.

If you're looking for a more general term, *refuge* is something that gives shelter.